# <img> downloading order - possible to set?

Tags: html, image

I understand the answer to this is most likely No... but I wanted to ask.

Is it possible to have one img start downloading first?

Basically I have a place holder GIF (that shows in the place of images as they download and I want to get that GIF downloaded as quickly as possible.

Am I able to somehow fast track the downloading of one img (the GIF)?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting an `<img>` tag with the gif as `src` before all other `<img>` tags and hide it with `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 2):

You could include that image as a data URI (if it's not too large), so that there's no separate network request made to fetch that image.  It will, of course, increase the size of the actual HTML content served.

You could also preload the image using JavaScript by making a new image object and setting the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can have placeholder gifs, eg (in css)

```
img{background-image:url(default_image.png)}
```

However, there is no good way to force one image to load before another. Browsers can load in whatever order they want.

You can make it more likely that the placeholder is downloaded first:

- If the placeholder is the same on all pages, it can get cached, so that on the next page, it is already loaded
- Make sure that the placeholder image is early in the page (makes the browser start loading earlier, a browser will probably load images in the order they appear in the html). If image shouldn't be displayed there, just do something like width="0" or visibility: hidden;
- Put the placeholder somewhere that the server serves quickly (avoid dynamically controlled folders - serve it in a static directory, eg. in the public/ folder for Apache)
- Make the placeholder image small
- Encourage caching by setting the cache headers so that the image expires in the far future (eg. 1 year), and so that the browser doesn't need to check back with the server. Also make sure private caching is off for the image (allow public server caching).

Data URIs are not that great. From **Wikipedia**:

> - Data URIs are not separately cached from their containing documents
>     (e.g. CSS or HTML files) so data are downloaded every time the
>     containing documents are redownloaded.
> - Referencing the same resource (such as an embedded small image) more
>     than once from the same document results in multiple copies of the
>     embedded resource. In comparison, an external resource can be
>     referenced arbitrarily many times, yet downloaded and decoded only
>     once.

If you use the placeholder image in 10 places on your page, you are going to have a much larger page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to dynamically load everything you don't want loaded before that gif (and is somewhat significant in size). Then, you could load that gif, and after it's done - load the rest of the content.

This could be done using Javascript. I'm not sure if there's already a library that helps you do this easily, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

I'd start off using something along the lines of "on document.ready, load that important gif, then when that finishes, load the rest":

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var myImportantImg = $('<img />');
    $(myImportantImg).on('load', function() { 
        // attach myImportantImg somewhere
        // load rest
    });
    $(myImportantImg).attr('src', 'http://url.to/myImg.gif');
});
```

Comment: This is trying to control the order by delaying the stuff you want to load after the placeholder. It doesn't necessarily speed up the placeholder loading much. You'll make the page load slower more than anything else

Comment: My understanding of the issue is that he wants this particular image to load ASAP. I suspect it's something important to the layout of his page. Indeed, the page will, overall, load slightly slower (very slightly) but the actual image should load faster if done properly.

Comment: Unlikely to make much difference. It just causes blocking (so that the browser doesn't download stuff in parallel connections).

Answer (score 0):

From what I read using [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in conjunction with css would be a good option:

```
img.placeholder {
    background: white url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat scroll left top;
}
```

Include the above code in a `<style>`-tag in the documents `<head>`-section to make sure it's loaded with the page, and tag the appropriate images with the `placeholder`-class:

```
<img src="..." class="placeholder">
```